# TBB concurrent_queue, how unsafe is unsafe_size?

Tags: c++, tbb

The documentation is not very clear on how unsafe `concurrent_queue::unsafe_size()` is.

The doxygen comment in the file `tbb/internal/concurrent_queue.h` mentions:

> Get size of queue; result may be invalid if queue is modified
>   concurrently

What I am interested in knowing is will it return a valid size at some point in the past, or may it return garbage ? (Provided that several threads are both reading and writing).

I am not interested in the exact value, but more on a "load" indication. I want to prevent my queue to explode in capacity when the consumer threads have a problem. I'd use `concurrent_bounded_queue` which as the name suggest has a capacity control, but I would lose the lock-free property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should treat it as garbage because it is marked unsafe.  I think it may actually return questionable numbers because if memory serves its really a difference between pushes and pops.  However even if it were 'safe' it would still only return a number that was valid in the past, that's one of the joys of wait free programming.
If you really need to reason about the counts store an atomic count in the class that holds the queue.

Is there a reason you are not using one of the tasking primitives in tbb instead of building your own?

Comment: The reason we are not using tasks is that the jobs are very small (i.e. synchronous send on a socket) and always the same (only the input parameter changes, not the function to be called). As such we belivie tasks are likely to be inappropriate for this kind of scenario. Still, we have not ruled out tasks completely yet, we are still evaluating the different possibilities. The queue seemed to be a better start (edit: and might try pipelines after, more suitable to our current "data flow").